# Apache Commons Net get FTP server's File Type

Tags: java, ftp, apache-commons-net

I am using apache.commons.net library for ftp download. In [this documentation](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html), it states

> To ensure correct operation with all servers, always specify the appropriate file type after connecting to the server.

It does provide

> FTPClient.setFileType

function to set File Type. But how do I know if the FTP server use ASCII or Binary? Is there a function to get the FTP server File Type? Or we just try different file types and see which one works?

THanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file type refers to the type of the files you are downloading, not the type of the server. If you are downloading text files you can set the file type to ASCII so that the line separators are changed to the local convention. If you are downloading binary files like images or office documents you should set the file type to binary so that the content is not corrupted.

You'll want to use binary almost always.

Comment: Thanks, Joni. I am sorry that I know so little about FTP. But if that's the case, why is the setFileType a function of FTPClient? If a FTP server stores both text and binary file and I set the File Type to Binary, will the text file download break? BTW, should I modify my original question so it's not confusing to other people?

Comment: In binary mode you get an exact copy of what's on the server, so it doesn't really break anything. ASCII mode exists because there's software (like old text editors) that only accepts one kind of line separators. If the FTP server converts the line separators while downloading you don't have to do it yourself in a separate step.